# String replace() is not working as expected

Tags: python, replace, find

I'm having some trouble with the `replace()` function in python. Here is my code :

```
string = input()
word = string.find('word')
if word >= 1:
    string = string.replace('word', 'word.2')
print(string)
```

The output gives `word`. Shouldn't it be `word.2`?
I'm confused. Any help?

Edit: After playing around with the issue for a bit, I've found that the question is now "Why is `string.find('word')` equal to 0 for input `word`?

Comment: I run on my machine which uses Python 3 and I found no issues.

Comment: What version of python are you using and what input are you testing with when this doesn't work? This works as expected on python 3.7

Comment: I have answered your 'edited' question in my answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of

```
word >= 1
```

write

```
word >= 0
```

string.find() returns the first occurence of the word. If your string is 'word' and you find 'word', it'll return 0 as the word 'word' occurs at index 0 first.

In python, arrays start at 0. The first character in a string is at index 0.

Therefore, 'word' in 'word' is at the first location, i.e. 0.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to use the find function, just do:

```
string = input()
string = string.replace('word', 'word.2')
```

But nevertheless, if i ran it in Python3, your code is correct ;-)
How does your input look like?

Answer (score 0):

it happens because first occurrence is treated as zero position, use below code

```
string = input().replace('word','word.2')
print(string)
```